# ResourceManager not picking up correct resx file

Tags: c#, .net, localization, mef, resourcemanager

I am having an issue getting the correct resource file entries and need some help ... here is my scenario

I have a series of projects that are a part of a large reporting solution that follow this format

Plugin.****Report

- Reference (folder)
- DataAccessLayer (folder)
- DataSets (folder)
- DataWrappers (folder)
- Localization  (folder)

  *.cs

Where * is the name of the report I am going to generate

The *.cs has an export statement so that I can pick it up using MEF (not sure if this is relevant, but thought it worth mentioning).  The namespace in *.cs is CompanyName.DataShaper.Plugin.*Report.  Due to the project name, and location of the files, I changed the default namespace for each project to be CompanyName.DataShaper.Plugin.*Report (it was just Plugin.*Report before my change).

Now for the problem .. inside of *.cs I am instantiating a ResourceManager.  That looks like this ...

```
_resourceManager =
                new ResourceManager("CompanyName.DataShaper.Plugin.*Report.Localization.*Report",
                    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

inside my resx designer file I have the following ...

```
internal static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
            get {
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
                    global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("CompanyName.DataShaper.Plugin.*Report.Localization.*Report", typeof(*Report).Assembly);
                    resourceMan = temp;
                }
                return resourceMan;
            }
```

My call to the resource manager looks like this ...

```
string resourceString = _resourceManager.GetString(resourceKey, _currrentCultureInfo);
```

where _currentCultureInfo is a a correct CultureInfo object.

I have 4 different resx files in my Localization folder for each project, (****Report.resx, ****Report.fr-ca.resx, ****Report.en-gb.resx, ****Report.de-de.resx).

When I make the call to the resource manager, I always get the entry from the .resx ... never any of the other language files, regardless of the CultureInfo object I pass into the call.  What have I messed up?

--> Quick update to my original question, but this does appear to be MEF related.  I instantiated my class the old fashioned way (new *Report()) and made the localization call and it works fine

Comment: What's with the *?  Do you actually get the satellite assemblies built?

Comment: I have about 20 different projects, that all follow the same naming convention.  THe * just represents a report name.  For example, one of them is TransactionReport.cs .. so there is a TransactionReport.res, TransactionReport.en-gb.resx, Plugin.TransactionReport etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I figured this out .. I am getting the .resx file because it is truly embedded into the main assembly.  The other files are getting built into separate dlls for each language, I then need to copy them into the same folder that I build my aggregate container from, my resource manager then sees all languages.